# Recursively move file into folder

Tags: cmd

please I need help with this script. I need to recursively move one particular file into one particular folder. The particular file is in the same folder as the particular folder.

To make it clear.

[image]

I have tried this, but its not working recursively, when I add the script into the Movie1 folder and from the script I remove the cd Movie folder, then it will move the file into that folder. But I need to make it run from the Root. Thanks for anykind of idea.

```
cd Movie folder
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /s "Subtitles.srt"') do move "%%~i" "Subtitles"
```

Comment: Please replace image with its text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there

You need the first line to optionally force the script to cd and look in relative local drive

Then add relative subdirs

```
cd /D "%~dp0"
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /s "Subtitles.srt"') do move "%%~i" "%%~dpiSubtitles"
```

If the folder names are `\Subtitles folder` then you need to add that at the end i.e. `"%%~dpiSubtitles folder"`

```
C:\Users>"E:\Movie folder\script.bat"

C:\Users>cd /D "E:\Movie folder\"

E:\Movie folder>for /F "delims=" %i in ('dir /b /s "Subtitles.srt"') do move "%~i" "%~dpiSubtitles"

E:\Movie folder>move "E:\Movie folder\Movie1\subtitles.srt" "E:\Movie folder\Movie1\Subtitles"
        1 file(s) moved.

E:\Movie folder>move "E:\Movie folder\Movie2\subtitles.srt" "E:\Movie folder\Movie2\Subtitles"
        1 file(s) moved.

E:\Movie folder>move "E:\Movie folder\Movie3\subtitles.srt" "E:\Movie folder\Movie3\Subtitles"
        1 file(s) moved.

E:\Movie folder>
```

Comment: What Im doing wrong here? I have Subtitles folder, in that folder is Subtitles file without extension. I run this code and it renames the Subtitles folder to Subtitles.srt, instead of the Subtitles file inside the folder. Thanks `for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /s Subtitles') do ren "%%~i" Subtitles.srt`

Comment: It works, thank you. I would never think that adding a smile like :-D would solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should not search the root directory recursively since the target files reside in a certain hierarchy depth:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=%~dp0Movie"    & rem /* (root directory containing the movie sub-directories;
                            rem     `%~dp0` points to the parent dir. of the script) */
set "_MDIR=Movie*"        & rem // (name or mask of movie sub-directories)
set "_SDIR=Subtitles"     & rem // (name of subtitles sub-sub-directory)
set "_NAME=Subtitles.srt" & rem // (pure name of the subtitles files)

rem // Iterate through the immediate sub-directories of the given root:
for /D %%J in ("%_ROOT%\%_MDIR%") do (
    rem // Check for existence of subtitles file:
    if exist "%%~J\%_NAME%" (
        rem // Check for non-existence of subtitles file to avoid overwriting:
        if not exist "%%~J\%_SDIR%\%_NAME%" (
            rem // Actually move subtitles file:
            move "%%~J\%_NAME%" "%%~J\%_SDIR%\%_NAME%"
        )
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```